# indexing list by tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

```
def greedy_decoder(input):
    flag = 0
    prob = 1
    ans_partial = np.zeros((1,maxlen_input))
    ans_partial[0, -1] = 2  #  the index of the symbol BOS (begin of sentence)
    for k in range(maxlen_input - 1):
        ye = model.predict([input, ans_partial])
        yel = ye[0,:]
        p = np.max(yel)
        mp = np.argmax(ye)
```

when trying to run this code this error pops up

```
yel = ye[0,:]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Any idea how to fix this ?? I'm using python 3.6
  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use advanced indexing with lists, but your code should work if you do

```
yel = ye[0]
```

which is actually equivalent to the current line for arrays that implement advanced indexing.

Comment: i changed it t ye[0] but now it gives me  list index out of range , any idea the source of this error ?